How to set custom lid actions per power plan in windows 11?
I have windows 11 Home 23H2. I'm trying to set different custom lid actions to different powerplans, which was available in earlier windows 10.
My Lid Close setting page mentions The change to this setting applies to all power plans. I tried some basic troubleshooting, but no luck.
My powerplan has the following advanced settings, which doesn't contain Lid actions.

I also tried some powerfg stuff, but it doesn't show GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 (which is lid close option).
I also tried to unhide the attributes but no luck.
However, I found it in registry setting, but changing the value gives me error Error writing the value

Help me solve the issue.
